# How can I use AlertDialog in an Adapter class?

Tags: java, android

I have send the Context to the Adapter

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Image> imagesList) {
        this.context = context;
        mImageList = imagesList;
    }
```

And I use AlertDialog this way:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
```

But I got error:

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Comment: Hey, if you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2):

send context as ActivityName.this/getActivity() from activity/fragment accordingly where you calling your adapter

Comment: If your adapter should know about activity to show dialog - it's also better to pass `Activity` instead of `Context` to constructor and save inside of adapter. This way you will never fall yourself into the crash if you forget about dialog inside of this adapter.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to define call back.

- define interface(callback with method )
- implement this call back in activity that holds adapter
- define object as parameter for your adapter like

  public ImageAdapter(Context context, List imagesList, Callback 
           callback) {
                  this.context = context;
                  mImageList = imagesList;
                 this.callback =callback;
              }
- inside your adapter call method inside your call back as you want your activity will listen to this action and inside this method in your activity you can create your alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

you should pass Activity instead of Context to the constructor of AlertDialog.Builder.and You have to make sure the activity is running when the dialog is running